# Format number input with the pattern #,####

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string-formatting

I would like to reach a number input format that always follow the pattern `#,####`. It's not a simple mask, if the value is `1` I should see `1,000`, if `20.32` should see `20,3200` and so on.

I tryed [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format):

```
formatCurrencyAmount(val) {
  var str = String(val)
  var unit_separator_index = str.indexOf('.')

  if (unit_separator_index < 0) return `${str},0000`

  var str_end = str.substring(unit_separator_index + 1, str.length - 1)
  var str_begin = str.substring(0, unit_separator_index - 1)

  if (str_end.length == 4) return `${str_begin},${str_end}`
  else if (str_end.length > 4) return `${str_begin},${str_end.padEnd(4, '0')}`
  else return `${str_begin},${str_end.substring(0, 4)}`
}

<NumberFormat
  value={ this.state.crypto_amount }
  format={ this.formatCurrencyAmount.bind(this) }
  allowNegative={ false }
  onValueChange={ this.handleCryptoAmountChange.bind(this) }
/>
```

No success.

How can I reach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this a reference for your requirement.
This method format the input number(4400000) => (IDR 4,400,000)

```
    calculateTotal = (total) => {
    return `IDR ${(total)
    .toString()
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")}`;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use the format property as string?

```
<NumberFormat 
    value={ this.state.crypto_amount } 
    displayType={'text'}
    format="#,####" 
/>
```